# Network request failed on Android with React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, ssl, ssl-certificate

My fetch() is working fine on iOS, but get error on Android with release build.

`Network request failed`

I have checked the setting on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application ...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...>
```

also I set the headers for fetch API

```
Accept: 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

If I want to fix the issue, is there any options I have to set ?

Or the problem may comes from the official document says, I have to adjust the SSL setting ?
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl

Comment: what is the version of Android?\

Comment: You mean build the project Android device version ? Android 12 and Android 8 all the same result. btw react native version is 0.60.5

Comment: try with android 6 if it's related with network security config it will work with Android 6 and show your fetch request remove the url if you want to

Comment: Can't find Android 6 device and simulator... may be I use M1 silicon, all the simulator shows terminated

Comment: Does your android emulator connect to the internet? like opening chrome and check if stackoverflow.com loads?

Comment: Internet is working, API error happens `TypeError: Network request failed`on release mode (debug mode is fine)

Comment: Use postman test API will see `Unable to verify the first certificate`

Comment: In case of Let's encrypt, the chain might not contain a trusted authority. You can put the url to the `WebView` component, it will tell you if no trusted authority is present. To check the chain use `openssl s_client -connect <domain>:443 -prexit` - but this should not be a problem if everything works in the dev mode. Just leaving a message for people who might've similar issue.